# how to select all the extjs dropdown values in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to a select option from extjs combo box.
Here in the below code `listElements` is giving only the visible options(which are shown in the screen) and not all the options.
Here am restricted to select one of the options which are available in the screen.
I want to select the value which are in the bottom of the list.
I don't find any option to drag down the list to select the desired option.

```
 List<WebElement> listElements = TestUtil.getWebDriver().findElements((By.className("x-boundlist-item")));
        for(WebElement ele : listElements){
            if(ele.getText().equals(TestUtil.getValue(DateTimeConstants.TIMEZONE_INPUT_VALUE))){
                ele.click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Please find the html :

This is the combo box html:

```
<input id="currentTimezone-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" type="text" style="width: 100%; -moz-user-select: text;" name="dateTimeData.selectedTimezone" value="-- Please Select --" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="">
```

Options are available below like this:

```
<div id="ext-gen1024" class="x-reset">
<div id="ext-gen1074" class="x-reset">
<div id="ext-gen1076" class="x-css-shadow" role="presentation" style="z-index: 19000; left: -9999px; top: -9995px; width: 355px; height: 296px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(136, 136, 136); display: none;"></div>
<div id="ext-gen1079" class="x-css-shadow" role="presentation" style="z-index: 19000; left: 20px; top: 321px; width: 355px; height: 296px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgb(136, 136, 136); display: none;"></div>
<div id="boundlist-1022" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default" tabindex="-1" style="left: 20px; top: 317px; width: 355px; z-index: 19001; height: 300px; display: none;">
<div id="boundlist-1022-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct" style="overflow: auto; height: 299px;">
<ul>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Africa/Abidjan</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Africa/Accra</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Africa/Addis_Ababa</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Africa/Algiers</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Africa/Asmara</li>

<li class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected" role="option">America/St_Lucia</li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks user1177636.I have updated the html..please let me know if you need more information.Actually I was using className..by mistake I have copied as tagName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I can reproduce this issue. The reason is that Selenium won't click on invisible elements, each of the invisible element's text will also be empty.

Here most of the combo list elements are invisible, so `ele.getText()` won't get you anything for them. As a result, you won't be able to compare the text with the one you want.

However, the workaround is, without using `ele.getText()` to get the text, you can try use `textContent` attribute of an element to get the text. Also, Selenium won't click on invisible element, so you need to use `Actions` `click()` rather than normal `click()`. Below is how you can do it.

```
List<WebElement> listElements = TestUtil.getWebDriver().findElements((By.cssSelector(".x-boundlist:not([style*='display: none'])")));
    for(WebElement ele : listElements){
        if(ele.getAttribute("textContent").equals(TestUtil.getValue(DateTimeConstants.TIMEZONE_INPUT_VALUE))) {
            // print out ele.getAttribute("textContent") if you want
            // ele.click(); ElementNotVisible exception may be thrown
            new Actions(TestUtil.getWebDriver()).click(ele).perform();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this we can use xpath in the following manner. The reason why a country is not selected is it is not visible and for invisible elements selenium cannot perform the action.
We have to first make the countries list visible by clicking on the input box. Once the list is visible we can select any of the country in the list.

```
// Code to make the country list visible
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'boundlist')]"));
element.click();

//To click on some country in the drop down 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'boundlist')]//ul//li[text() = 'Africa/Abidjan']")).click();

//To make a reusable method
public void selectCountry(String countryName)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'boundlist')]//ul//li[text() = '" +countryName +"']"));
}
```

Comment: Hai sorry for the delay. Even if the data in the drop down is hidden from us after the click still selenium can find it. When we say hidden/disabled we just mean selenium can't see it in the dom. Try out my code let me know if it worked or not. This is what I use in my current project.

Comment: Thanks both of you.I have tried  user1177636 approach and it worked fine for me.Will try Vinay's approach and let you guys know.Thanks a lot again to both of you.